Permission error when sharing with other users in Looker Studio
I'm designing some Looker dashboards that consume BigQuery data.
I have data from different tables, but they are all from the same project. Today when I went to send the invitations for access, colleagues got access but instead of graphs and tables, a box appeared with the following message:
"No access to dataset - Permissions are insufficient for the underlying dataset"
Could this be related to the project in Big Query?
I asked a person who has full access to the databases to view the dashboard and she also couldn't access the same charts, which made me a little confused about the permission issues

What permissions did you give and to what role? Is the connection to BigQuery via a service account? Refer to these docs from Google on how it should be setup.
https://cloud.google.com/looker/docs/db-config-google-bigquery
https://cloud.google.com/looker/docs/access-control-and-permission-management

Check the configuration for Data source access. Click on any of the boxes from your end then on the right panel find Data source -> Edit data source -> bottom panel appears -> Data Credentials. See what type of Credentials you have configured or who has the access, I got the same issue when I chose Viewer's credentials.
